# Clear out an error message instead of appending with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In this HTML form that I have I would like to warn the user that he has to enter a level in the inputbox, if he clicks the button again I would like to clear off the error message and print it out again. I would like to also add more error messages but anything that I add as an error message appends to the end of the previous message.

```js
function validateForm () {
    var msg = ""
      , result = true;

    if (document.ExamEntry.name.value === "") {
        msg = document.createTextNode("You Must Indicate Your Level");
        document.getElementById('name-msg').appendChild(msg);
        document.getElementById('name-msg').style.color="red";
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="ExamEntry" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    <span id="name-msg"></span>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validateForm();">
</form>
```

here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/dikikoxori/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function validateForm () {
    var result = true;

    if (document.ExamEntry.name.value === "") {
      document.getElementById('name-msg').innerHTML= "You Must Indicate Your Level";
        document.getElementById('name-msg').style.color="red";
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="ExamEntry" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    <span id="name-msg"></span>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validateForm();">
</form>
```

Comment: it is close enough to what I'm looking for, as the answer above is there any way to clear off the message if the user clicks the submit button again and there's actual text in the input box?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what are you looking for?

```js
function validateForm(){

    var result = true;
    var msg = "";
    if(document.ExamEntry.name.value===""){
        msg = document.createTextNode("You Must Indicate Your Level");
        var span = document.getElementById('name-msg');
        while( span.firstChild ) {
            span.removeChild( span.firstChild );
        }
        span.appendChild(msg)
        document.getElementById('name-msg').style.color="red";
    } else {
        var span = document.getElementById('name-msg');
        while( span.firstChild ) {
            span.removeChild( span.firstChild );
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="ExamEntry" method="POST">

    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" /><span id="name-msg">             </span>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"        onclick="validateForm();" />

</form>
```

Comment: Yes it is close enough to what I'm looking for, however is there any way to clear off the message if the user clicks the submit button again and there's actual text in the input box?

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the html like

```js
function validateForm() {

  var result = true;

  var msg = "";


  if (document.ExamEntry.name.value === "") {
    msg = document.createTextNode("You Must Indicate Your Level");
    document.getElementById('name-msg').appendChild(msg);
    document.getElementById('name-msg').style.color = "red";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('name-msg').innerHTML = '';
  }




}
```

```html
<form name="ExamEntry" method="POST">

  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" /><span id="name-msg"></span>

  <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validateForm();" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may possibly use `innerHTML`:

```js
function validateForm() {
  var msg = "",
    result = true;
  if (document.ExamEntry.name.value === "") {
    msg = "You Must Indicate Your Level";
  }
  document.getElementById('name-msg').innerHTML = msg;
}
```

```css
#name-msg {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="ExamEntry" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
  <span id="name-msg"></span>
  <br/>
  <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validateForm();">
</form>
```